# value of text.replace() to another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code to clear and paste text after clicking a button. This text is pasted into two different textareas and therefore my code has to clean up the intercepted content a bit differently. The problem is that it doesn't work to pass the content to another variable...

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  $('.quoteMsg').click(function() {
    var txt = $(this).closest('.replyBox').find('.replyMsg').html().trim();
    var txtau = $(this).closest('.replyBox').find('.replyMsgau').text().trim();
    txt = txt.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ' ');
    txt = txt.replace(/<p class="c0">/gi, '');
    txt = txt.replace(/<\/p>/gi, '');
    txt = txt.replace(/&lt;/g, "<");
    txt = txt.replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
    txt = txt.replace(/&amp;/g, "&");
    txt = txt.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
    txt = txt.replace(/&#039;/g, "'");
var txtq = txt; //it doesn't work to pass the whole value to the txtq variable
//txtq = txt; //also not working
    txtq = txt;
    txtq = txt.replace(/<blockquote>/gi, '');
    txtq = txt.replace(/<\/blockquote>/gi, '[hr][i]' + txtau + '[/i]: '); 
    
var txte = txt; //it doesn't work to pass the whole value to the txte variable
//txte = txt; //also not working
    txte = txt.replace(/<blockquote>/gi, '[quote]');
    txte = txt.replace(/<\/blockquote>/gi, '[/quote]\n');
    txte = txt.replace(/<blockquote>/gi, '');

    $("textarea[name='tresckomentapisz']").val('[quote]' + txtq + '[/quote]\n' + txtau + ', ');
    $("textarea[name='editkomtxt']").val(txte);


  });
});
```

I want `txtq` and `txte` to format the value differently for `<blockquote>`, but data transfer from `txt` doesn't work - why?

I need this efect for `<quote>`:
`console.log(txtq + '|' + txte + '|' + txt);//[hr][i]etc[/i] | [quote]\n`

but is working like that:
`console.log(txtq + '|' + txte + '|' + txt);//<blockquote>|<blockquote>|`

Comment: What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? Assigning values to variables does work. What happens that you don't expect?

Comment: @Pointy hi, I edited my post for a better explanation with examples

Comment: @Albert YES!! i missed that... add an answer and I will gladly award a point for help in solving the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `txtq` and `txte`, you are modifiying `txt` var.

Insted of:

```
txtq = txt.replace(/<blockquote>/gi, '');
```

try:

```
txtq = txtq.replace(/<blockquote>/gi, '');
```